# Error message 1 Failed to repack shapefile in QGIS 3.10.3 when saving changes to layer

Tags: qgis, polygon, save, error-1

I am self taught using QGIS 3.10.3 on Windows 10.

Over time I have a project dealing with 10 Parishes with maps to show land use and ownership using 20 layers that take data from individual CSV files, one for each parish.

I have recently redone the CSV files and relinked the files to the relevant layer. When checking the layers I find some ploygons have vanished. The data is still in the Atribute Table but the polygon does not show.

If I redraw the polygon it still does not show but data is added to the Atribute file. When saving the layer I am now getting a message saying

> Error 1 "Failed to repack the Layer".

I have modified the polygon and saved it and I dont get the message but if I try again I do. I keep saving the project file but I am having to keep adding polygons to get he map to draw and then delete the extra data from the atrbute table.
I have reloaded QGIS.
I have also  tried removing a laver, say land use,  and worked on the other owners layer for the Parish When completed I duplicate the Owners layer and rename itan land use but the same issue arises with "Failed to rrepack" message. Advice please

Comment: If a polygon doesn't draw you might run the Check Validity tool to see if there are errors.  You could also run Fix Geometries.  If you add polys and they don't save you might make sure they all have unique IDs, such as FIDs in a shapefile.

Comment: Many thanks for the advice..I have checked all the ID's and found some errors, now fixed. I also checked Validity with 2 errors now fixed. I have now split my project into two, one with land use layers and one with owner layers . The missing polygons seem to be there and all seems OK. I have been editing the polygons but when I try to save i still get Error 1 unable to repack layer. I have also tried "Save Layer Edits" with the same result. I am worried now that I will lose data if I cant save it

Comment: Are you linking the csv data to polygons in a shapefile, geopackage or some other dataset type?  Can you edit your polygons without the join, and save that, then do your join?

Comment: This project started about 2 yrs ago with one layer on which I drew pologons and then linked them to a CSV file added to the project . When I drew a polygon I added the ID link to the CSV which then linked to other fields such as Tithe number, use, area, names etc all held in the CSV and called up via layer properties. The project has now grown to 20 layers with 20+ tif files from which polygons are traced, road layers, water lavers . I have tried another layer which works fine and will save, I just have the two probllem layers so far that wont save. Do I remove the link and try to save?

Comment: I also found my PC was running very slow and QGS often "Froze"- Not responding message. I also found on the problem layers the auxillary storage in Layer Properties was showing 15 or so Targets that I had not put there for things like text propertes . I just deleted them. I have saved a copy of the problem layer as a Layer definition file but the CSV is not linked to it. I can edit that and it saves. Maybe I should just use that layer and delete the old one

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if you:

- Have data from CSV or MS Excel linked to a layer A
- Have at least one duplicate layer B from layer A
- Put layer A and B in edit mode, make changes in both layers and then leave edit mode in either layer A or B.

This error is handled very ungracefully, resulting in loosing the geometries of some features in layer A (and B since they are duplicates). Since the error occurs during saving, it cannot be undone. You will have to manually add the lost geometries again.

To prevent this from happening:

- Make sure you never start edit mode on both duplicate layers at the same time. Before you start editing B you close editing mode on A and vice versa.
- Make regular backups of the shapefile by copying all associated files to a separate directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).